# What is the effect of one point of block skill?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have been unable to find the exact value of one point of blocking. The unofficial Elder Scrolls pages and other wikis do not list a value for blocking.

As an example, [for heavy armor one point adds 0.4% armor](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Heavy_Armor).

The block value seems important because I want to find out how much fortify block to enchant on my stuff. the USEP lists the max block mitigation as 85% (if you are looking at [this page](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Block#Skill_Usage)) or 80% (if you are looking at [this page](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Fortify_Block)).

Comment: Good question, I'm surprised to see neither of the two popular Skyrim wikis has a formula for blocking effectiveness. Considering the other resistances are capped at 85%, I'd venture a guess that blocking is the same.

Comment: @kotekzot Most of the information comes from these threads: http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1313851-complete-character-design-freedom-damage-resist-caps-and-ridiculous-damage-thread-7/ and you will notice that they claim they have a great deal of information on block but it has not been publicized yet. The block section has said that same thing for a few versions of that thread now

Comment: @James, ah, I didn't know that, thanks for the link. Hopefully it'll be available soon.

Answer (score 17):

The numbers on UESP are likely guesstimates added before the [Creation Kit](http://www.creationkit.com/Main_Page) was released.

According to actual game values and assuming no other combat modifications, the base block value (`fBlockSkillBase`) is 0% mitigation at 0 skill, and each point of skill increases that mitigation by 2% (`fBlockSkillMult`) up to a maximum of 70% (`fBlockMax`).

However, there are several dozen other factors—ranging from whether you're staggered to whether you're using a weapon to block—that affect your block mitigation percentage. You can find these multipliers in the Creation Kit by going to *Gameplay → Settings...* and searching for "block".

Comment: how did I know? HOW DID I KNOW? ;-) (you really should try playing some other game, variety is the spice of life friend, lol)

Comment: @Ender [Currently the top user for Final Fantasy 13-2](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/final-fantasy-13-2/topusers) too :)

Comment: Does this say that at skill 35 in block you would have the maximum block mitigation (35*2% = 70%)?  I'm not sure how that could be right, maybe I am just misinterpreting something.

Comment: @F.J It's under ideal conditions. As I mentioned, there are a number of other factors and multipliers that affect your mitigation outside of your block skill.

Comment: @Mark Nice, I have had a hard time enjoying any FF game from 9 out sadly. They just don't make them like they used to. FF13 looks spectacular, but I pretty much hate almost everything else about it. (the story line is supurb, its the gameplay I can't stomach)

Answer (score 1):

Not an exact number, but the answer to your larger question seems to be: With a Daedric shield, you need a total of +32.5% increased block effectiveness to reach the block mitigation cap of 85% at a block skill of 100.

So, you could achieve that with 4 ranks in the shield wall perk, and a non-enchanted shield.  Different shields seem to have different block ratings.  A glass shield needs more like 37.5%. A hide shield would seem to need around 46%.

Information taken from [this thread](http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1294892-max-block-absorb/page__view__findpost__p__19589757).

Comment: Nice set of information, but I fail to see how this answers the question...

Comment: Well, that depends on what you consider the question.  The question was "what does one point of block skill do? The block value seems important because I want to find out how much fortify block to enchant on my stuff."  So no, it didn't answer what one point of block does, but it did answer how much fortify you need to maximize block effectiveness.